# Resolving ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined for Select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

And it is pointing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPMkw.jpg

I did some tweaking such as commenting out the options and it pointed to 
the select element itemBrand:

```html
<select id="itemBrand" name="itemBrand" formControlName="itemBrand" class="form-control btn-sm brand" (change)="changeBrand($event)" required>
```

So I am thinking that the formControl validator is having an issue with my select element. But I cannot fix it.

Here is the initialization of the form using form builder:

**typescript**:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getBrands();
    this.itemAddForm = this.fb.group({
        itemName: ['', Validators.required],
        itemBrand: ['Select a Brand', Validators.required],
        // ....
    });
}
```

**html**:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="itemAddForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="itemName">Item Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="itemName" name="itemName" formControlName="itemName" class="form-control input-md" required
                    type="text">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="itemAddForm.get('itemName').errors && itemAddForm.get('itemName').touched">
                <p class="error-message text-danger"><span class="error-icon text-danger">!
                    </span>{{itemAddForm.get('itemName').errors.msg || 'Please enter an item name.'}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="itemBrand">Brand</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <select id="itemBrand" name="itemBrand" formControlName="itemBrand"
                        class="form-control btn-sm brand" (change)="changeBrand($event)" required>
                        <!-- <option [value]="" disabled>Select a brand</option> -->
                        <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [value]="brand?.brand">{{ brand?.brand }}</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="itemBrand.invalid">
                        Select a brand.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: how do you define `itemBrand` in your ts file?

Comment: itemBrand is defined under the this.fb.group

this.itemAddForm = this.fb.group({
      itemName: ['', Validators.required],
      **itemBrand: ['Select a Brand', Validators.required ],**
      ....
    });

Comment: That means that your component has no property called `itemBrand`.

Comment: itemBrand and itemName are both defined the same way. so no that is not the issue. anyway, it is already fixed thanks to Ramesh Rajendran.

Comment: Notice that in your template you arent accessing `itemName` directly, always through `itemsAddForm.get`, thats why its not triggering an error. Most likely with Ramesh approach, the `Select a brand` message wont be displayed under any condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try `*ngIf="itemBrand?.invalid"` instead of `*ngIf="itemBrand.invalid"` for a safe condition check.

Comment: hi Ramesh! Thank you so much for that! It fixed the problem.